# bind event to all anchor tags except data-rel= back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, anchor

I am working on a hybrid application using jQuery Mobile. The issue is I want to handle clicks to all anchor tags present in the application except `data-rel` back buttons.

Consider this code:

```
<a data-rel="back">leave me</a>
```

I cannot just select all `a` elements like so:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
    alert("whooi handled all anchors")
}
```

Anyone have a suggestion on how to achieve this?

Comment: @ jonas i do always if ans is correct, anyway tx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using the [Not Selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$('a:not([data-rel=back])')
```

You could also use the [Attribute Not Equal Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/):

```
$('a[data-rel!=back]')
```

Does this work for you?